# customize functionality of share buttons under each blog post

Tags: theme-development

i am working on a magazine theme design and i wanted to know how the thumbs-up button functionality under each blog post found at http://www.movenourishbelieve.com/ is implemented.

i am using a plugin called Simple Share Buttons Adder which only adds buttons.

i have already implemented the on click functionality using javascript. Here is the script-

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#thumbup").click(function(){
              $("#hidden-like").toggle();
            });
        });
</script>
```

The problem that i am facing is when i click on the thumbs-up button under a particular blog post, social icons under all blog posts open up. How can i make my thumbs up button open share icons only on the post under which it is placed.

Also, once the user clicks on any of the share buttons, it has to only share that post.

Here is the html of my blog post container-

```
    <div id="entry-07">

                        <?php the_post(); ?>

                        <div class="entry-image-three-col">
                            <?php
                                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                    the_post_thumbnail('smaller');
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="entry-title-three-col">

                            <h2>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class = "index_blog_title" title="<?php _e('Permalink to ', 'kelle'); ?><?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </h2>

                        </div>

                        <div class="entry-excerpt-three-col">

                            <p> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>

                        </div>

                        <div class="read-more">

                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">READ MORE</a>

                            <div id="hidden-like" id="post-<?=$wp_query->posts[0]->ID;?>-like">

                                <?php //pinboard_social_bookmarks(); 
                                    echo do_shortcode('[ssba]');
                                ?>

                            </div>  <!--hidden-like end -->

                        </div>  <!-- read-more end -->

                        <div class = "thumb">

                            <img src="http://localhost/wp_the_vitality_project/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/fb_thumb.jpg" id = "thumbup">

                        </div>



</div>  <!-- entry-07 end-->
```

Thanks

Comment: jQuery code will depends on how your HTML is setup. Post your HTML code too for this section.

Comment: @Roberthue added html code

Comment: Well, you told the `id="hidden-like"` divs to `toggle()`. And the ID is present with every post in the loop, so all toggle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this will be your jQuery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.thumbup').on('click', function(){
            $(this).parents('.entry').find(".hidden-like").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But to use it, you will have to change couple of IDs in classes or you can also add classes with IDs.

You can not use ID as you wish. `The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element.` So it has to be unique on a page.

1. Using ID for more than one HTML element is not correct.
2. You have more then 1 IDs in single element, it's again not correct.

   ```
   <div id="entry-07" class="entry">

     <?php the_post(); ?>

     <div class="entry-image-three-col">
       <?php
         if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
           the_post_thumbnail('smaller');
         }
       ?>
     </div>

     <div class="entry-title-three-col">

       <h2>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class = "index_blog_title" title="<?php _e('Permalink to ', 'kelle'); ?><?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
       </h2>

     </div>

     <div class="entry-excerpt-three-col">

       <p> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>

     </div>

     <div class="read-more">

       <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">READ MORE</a>

       <div class="hidden-like" id="post-<?=$wp_query->posts[0]->ID;?>-like">

         <?php //pinboard_social_bookmarks(); 
           echo do_shortcode('[ssba]');
         ?>

       </div>  <!--hidden-like end -->

     </div>  <!-- read-more end -->

     <div class="thumb">

       <img src="http://localhost/wp_the_vitality_project/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/fb_thumb.jpg" class="thumbup">

     </div>

   </div><!-- entry-07 end-->
   ```

I made following changes.

1. `entry` class in `<div id="entry-07">`
2. change `hidden-like` id to class because it already has ID.
3. change `thumbup` id to class.